# How to convert/update already published legacy packaged app into new version of packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published a packaged app years ago. Now, Google introduces a new packaged apps concept and all published packaged apps are recognized as legacy.

I've aligned my application with the new concept but when I'm trying publish the app to Chrome Store it always fails on:

```
 An error occurred: Item type may not be changed after initial upload.
```

Is there a way how to convert/update an existing packaged app on new concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to change the type. Note that new-style packaged apps aren't yet discoverable in the store. When that changes and end users are able to browse new-style packaged apps, there will also be a facility for updating legacy app types to the new type. Stay tuned!

**Update 5/7/2013**: Apps are now discoverable for users who are able to install and launch them through the App Launcher (Windows and ChromeOS users on dev channel). The type-switching feature isn't yet available, but this is actually a desirable situation because switching a popular app to a non-legacy app type would immediately reduce its visibility to that smaller set of users.