# Update extension to packaged app in webstore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I currently have an extension published in chrome web store. 
Now with some additional features, It made more sense to update that to an packaged app.
I have changed the extension to Packaged App.
Now my question is, As I want to retain my current extension users to use Packaged app, Can I directly update the zip file of the New pacakged app to the extension in the chrome store?
Will there be any hiccups in this process? Or do I have to host my new Packaged app separately in web-store (Doing this, I will lose my existing users )?

Comment: You'll want to follow this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882513/how-to-convert-update-already-published-legacy-packaged-app-into-new-version-of/15890545#15890545